# Python numpy C++ bindings

Tags: python, numpy

Just wondering one simple thing:

Does the majority of numpy code have bindings to C++?
(Which would make it run almost as fast as native C++ code)

Or is it all in python?

Comment: A large portion of the `numpy` code is written in C. Some of it is written in Fortran. A lot of it is written in Python. Well-written `numpy` code is comparable in speed to C code.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to bind NumPy (Python) code to C++ and use the NumPy arrays in place is `xtensor`: https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor-python

In case you ever need that extra bit of speed.

Answer (score 0):

[The documention of the numpy array API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html) gives a lot of examples of how you can handle numpy arrays in C (and C++, it's the same API) or handling data existing in a C/C++ program through numpy.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but the answers to this question are actually quite ridiculous and don't answer the simple question OP is posing.

To answer specifically: most of NumPy is implemented in C/C++ and was originally bound to Python with [SWIG](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIG.html#SWIG) or through other manual procedures implemented by its creators. I am not up to date on its modernization but I would not be surprised if another framework for binding it to scripting languages is used today. NumPy is part of the larger SciPy project and a great read on this is [this](http://web.mit.edu/dvp/Public/numpybook.pdf) resource. All objects in NumPy are objects implemented in C/C++ - so there is some marshaling/type conversion that happens between your wrapper program (Python) and the underlying implementation in C/C++.

This is a complex topic that requires knowledge of C/C++ in order to fully grasp how the translation process happens between the two languages, but the importance here is that the methods and functions available to you in NumPy are **not** operating "under the hood" in the same way that operations using the Python standard library would be performed.